# More efficient way of formatting optional text string

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I have written this piece of code:

```
@staticmethod
def __ver_upload_url(document_type, document_subtype=None):

    verification_base = 'verification/{0}/'.format(document_type)
    verification_base += '{0}/'.format(document_subtype) if document_subtype is not None else ''
```

I was wondering if there was a cleaner, more Pythonic way of formatting the URL path in just one line. I initially had:

```
verification_base = 'verification/{0}/{1}'.format(document_type, document_subtype) \
if document_subtype is not None else 'verification/{0}/'.format(document_type)
```

I think it is cleaner and more readable now, but maybe there is still a better way.

Note: I am trying to generate a path for a Django file that must be uploaded, and files have always types, but not always subtypes (as in categories and subcategories). I want to add a subdirectory to specify the subtype only if the file has a subtype, and if not leave it inside the folder named as the type.

### Edit

I had to escalate my function and now it looks something like:

```
def verification_url(document_type, document_subtype=None, company=False, company_administrator=False):
    verification_base = 'verification/'
    verification_base += 'companies/' if company or company_administrator else ''
    verification_base += 'admins/' if company_administrator else ''
    verification_base += '{0}/'.format(document_type)
    verification_base += '{0}/'.format(document_subtype) if document_subtype is not None else ''

    def function(instance, filename):
        id = instance.id if company else instance.user.id
        return verification_base + '{user_id}/{filename}'.format(id=id, filename=filename)
```

I was wondering that maybe I could write a URL builder that depends upon a list of elements that will be inserted into a string limited by slashes, to reduce the length of my code, or make it reusable at least.

What are your suggestions to improve the efficiency / scalability of the code?

Comment: IMHO `if document_subtype: 
verification_base += '{0}/'.format(document_subtype)` is more pythonic.

Comment: @georgexsh please check my edit. My function now is larger and it could make more sense to try and build something a bit more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regularity of the tokens you are combining suggests a `join`-based approach:

```
bits = ('verification', 'companies', 'admins', document_type, document_subtype)
flags = (1, company or company_administrator, company_administrator, document_type, document_subtype)

verification_base = '/'.join([b for b, f in zip(bits, flags) if f]) + '/'
```

Comment: You are a hacker. I was writing something similar with zip and join but did not get it right just yet. Thank you so much

Comment: My code was: `def url_builder(struct):
    string = '/'.join([string if condition else '' for string, condition in zip(*struct)])`

Comment: But I was packing the values incorrectly in zip, now I get how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: I see :) note however that there is nothing wrong with a couple more lines and being explicit.

Comment: That is true! Which one should we follow in python's zen? Explicit is better than implicit or simple is better than complex? :)

Comment: For private things I'd go with whatever feels most pleasing, at work I choose for whatever my co-workers won't rip my head off when maintaining it :D that would definitely be a couple of if-blocks and not the ternary operator.

Comment: Note that there is also a shorter version of the ternary `a+b if c else d`: `(d, a+b)[c]` ;)

Comment: Wow that was really cool. But would not you have to convert the evaluated bool to an integer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161939/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-j-c-rocamonde).